# Create new columns by adding a sequence of months to a date column

Tags: r, date, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I have data with a date column:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

Y = data.table(X = c("2012-12-31", "2021-10-31"))

            X  
1: 2012-12-31
2: 2021-10-31
```

I want to add a sequence of months, from 1 to `x`, to the dates in column "X". The result should be a set of new columns, "X_1", "X_2", ... "X_x":

```
            X          X_1          X_2    X_x
1: 2012-12-31   2013-01-31   2013-02-28 .. (2012-12-31) %m+% months(x)
2: 2021-10-31   2021-11-30   2021-12-31 .. (2021-10-31) %m+% months(x)
```

I've tried several things that didn't work, such as:

```
  Y[ , c(paste0("X_", 1:15))] = AddMonths(Y$X, c(1:15)) %>% LastDayInMonth()
  Y[ , c(paste0("X_", 1:15)) := AddMonths(as.IDate(X), c(1:15)) %>% LastDayInMonth()]
```

I want to create 15 columns based on this operation, so I want to avoid `for` loops. My real data have 80K rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `%m+%` and `months` are vectorized.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

n = 3 
nm = paste0("x", "_", seq(n))
m = rep(seq(n), each = nrow(d))
d[ , (nm) := split(x %m+% months(m), m)]
d
#             x        x_1        x_2        x_3
# 1: 2012-12-31 2013-01-31 2013-02-28 2013-03-31
# 2: 2021-10-31 2021-11-30 2021-12-31 2022-01-31
```

---

**Explanation**:

Set the maximum number of months in the sequence to be added to each value in the date column (e.g. `n = 3`). Create a vector of column names to which the result should be assigned (`nm = paste0("x", "_", seq(n))`). Create a vector of months to be added (`m = rep(seq(n), each = nrow(d))`) to the date column. Add the months in 'm' to the dates in 'x' (`x %m+% months(m)`). Split the result by the number of months added (`split(x %m+% months(m), m)`) to a list. Use the fundamental property of `data.table`, "*each element of the list becomes a column in the resulting `data.table`*", and assign the resulting columns by reference (`:=`).

---

```
d = data.table(x = as.Date(c("2012-12-31","2021-10-31")))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I pasted a wrong version of the answer: `months(1)` should be `months(i-1)`. Corrected now.

In a for loop we can do it like this:

```
library(lubridate) #%m+%
Y=data.table("X"=as.Date(c("2012-12-31","2021-10-31")))

for (i in 2:15) {
  Y <- Y %>% 
    mutate(col= X %m+% months(i-1))
  colnames(Y)[i] <- paste0("X_",i-1)
}
```

```
 X        X_1        X_2        X_3        X_4        X_5        X_6        X_7        X_8        X_9       X_10       X_11       X_12
1: 2012-12-31 2013-01-31 2013-02-28 2013-03-31 2013-04-30 2013-05-31 2013-06-30 2013-07-31 2013-08-31 2013-09-30 2013-10-31 2013-11-30 2013-12-31
2: 2021-10-31 2021-11-30 2021-12-31 2022-01-31 2022-02-28 2022-03-31 2022-04-30 2022-05-31 2022-06-30 2022-07-31 2022-08-31 2022-09-30 2022-10-31
         X_13       X_14
1: 2014-01-31 2014-02-28
2: 2022-11-30 2022-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged with `dplyr` I assume `tidyverse` is allowed, too.

Starting with a list for the 2 dates you have.

A function taking a `date` as input adds from starting month as many months as choosen in the additional argument.

The function is then applied with `map` to the list of initial dates. This is then transformed into a `data.frame`.

- *Example shows only `n=6`*
- *Contains loop*

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

f <- function(x, n = 5) {
  yy <- x
  for (i in seq(n)) {
    yy <- append(yy, x %m+% months(i))
  }
  return(yy)
}

l <- list(("2012-12-31"), ("2021-10-31"))
l |>
  map(lubridate::as_date) |>
  map(n = 6, f) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(l) |>
  t() |> as.data.frame()
#>                    V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
#> 2012-12-31 2012-12-31 2013-01-31 2013-02-28 2013-03-31 2013-04-30 2013-05-31
#> 2021-10-31 2021-10-31 2021-11-30 2021-12-31 2022-01-31 2022-02-28 2022-03-31
#>                    V7
#> 2012-12-31 2013-06-30
#> 2021-10-31 2022-04-30
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```r
data.table("X"=c("2012-12-31","2021-10-31")) %>% mutate(date=as.Date(X), seq=row_number(), date2=date %m+% months(15)) %>% 
  group_by(seq) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('date'), names_to = 'name', values_to = 'date') %>% 
  tidyr::complete(date=full_seq(date, period = 1)) %>% fill(X) %>% 
  mutate(year=year(date), month=month(date)) %>% group_by(X,year, month) %>% 
  slice_tail(n=1) %>% ungroup %>% group_by(X) %>%
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(X,names_from = row, names_prefix = 'X',values_from = date)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 17
# Groups:   X [2]
  X          X1         X2         X3         X4         X5         X6         X7         X8         X9         X10        X11       
  <chr>      <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
1 2012-12-31 2012-12-31 2013-01-31 2013-02-28 2013-03-31 2013-04-30 2013-05-31 2013-06-30 2013-07-31 2013-08-31 2013-09-30 2013-10-31
2 2021-10-31 2021-10-31 2021-11-30 2021-12-31 2022-01-31 2022-02-28 2022-03-31 2022-04-30 2022-05-31 2022-06-30 2022-07-31 2022-08-31
# … with 5 more variables: X12 <date>, X13 <date>, X14 <date>, X15 <date>, X16 <date>
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```